# Is there a type of number sequence that has a nth number actually have multiple answers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, soft-question

I am just looking for what this type of number sequence this is called?

Example:
The logic of the sequence is, take the previous numbers in the sequence and add them together in every possible way to come out with the next "n" numbers.

1,1,2,3-4,

n1=1 n2=1 n3=2 n4=3&4

What category sequence does this fall into?
let me know if you need more details.

Comment: What you're looking for is probably a sequence of sets, not a sequence of numbers.

Comment: A sequence is defined as a function from $\mathbb{N}$. Since functions can't be multivalued (in most of math anyway), such a "sequence" is not defined.

Comment: Would you consider 7 to be a possible value for $n_5$?

Answer (score 1):

These types of sequences come up in DNA and protein sequencing where they are called [sequence motifs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_motif).

Answer (score 0):

From what you write, it seems you are defining the following sequence of sets:
$(A_n)_{n\ge 1}$ such that $A_1=A_2=\{1\}$ and $A_{n+1}$ is the set of all possible non-empty sums with values in $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ and such that they do not belong to $A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$.

Well, at this point, it is not difficult to prove by induction that
$$\forall n\ge 4, \,\,\,A_n=\{2^{n-3}+1,2^{n-3}+2,\ldots,2^{n-2}\}.$$

Comment: Are there any sequences of sets based on formulas?